# Summarising columns of hours and minutes in python

Tags: python, pandas

I have a column in pandas composed of time in hour and minutes and I am wondering if there is some simple way to summarise the time points.

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'Time': ['00:46','02:21','05:20','07:02']})
```

Something similar to:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'Values': [87,3,43,32]})
df['Values'].sum()
```

I have tried converting the column using `pd.to_datetime()` but I still don't find any way to summarise the column.

```
pd.to_datetime(df['Time'], format='%H:%M').dt.time
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can aggregate `timedelta`:

```
pd.to_timedelta(df['Time']+':00').sum()
```

Output:

```
Timedelta('0 days 15:29:00')
```